# How to merge two SQL tables without duplicates of a single column?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I import all values from a different SQL Table only importing lines that have a non duplicate 'b' entry. Because 'b' symbols a unique string in my tables. Both tables have ca. 5mio entry's.

```
A_Table
structure
'id', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'

B_Table
structure
'a', 'b', 'c'
```

Add to A_Table from B_Table
where 'A_Table.b' !found in 'B_Table.b'

Example:

A_Table

```
    1, "a1", "Hallo1", "c", "d"
    2, "a1", "Hallo2", "c", "d"
    3, "a1", "Hallo3", "c", "d"
    4, "a1", "Hallo5", "c", "d"
    5, "a1", "Hallo7", "c", "d"
    6, "a1", "Hallo8", "c", "d"
```

B_Table

```
    "a2", "Hallo1", "c"
    "a2", "Hallo2", "c"
    "a2", "Hallo3", "c"
    "a2", "Hallo4", "c"
    "a2", "Hallo5", "c"
    "a2", "Hallo6", "c"
    "a2", "Hallo9", "c"
```

A_Table after query

```
    1, "a1", "Hallo1", "c", "d"
    2, "a1", "Hallo2", "c", "d"
    3, "a1", "Hallo3", "c", "d"
    4, "a1", "Hallo5", "c", "d"
    5, "a1", "Hallo7", "c", "d"
    6, "a1", "Hallo8", "c", "d"
    7, "a2", "Hallo4", "c", ""
    8, "a2", "Hallo6", "c", ""
    9, "a2", "Hallo9", "c", ""
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What do you mwan by "import"?

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/275923/150107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `union all`:

```
insert into a_table (a, b, c, d)
    select a, b, c, ''
    from b_table b 
    where not exists (select 1 from a_table a where a.b = b.b);
```

If you care about performance, you want an index on `a_table(b)`.

This assumes that `id` is assigned automatically.

If you just want a result set, then `union all`:

```
select id, a, b, c, d
from b_table a
union all
select a.max_id + row_number() over (order by b.a, b.b, b.c),
       b.a, b.b, b.c, ''
from b_table b cross join
     (select max(id) as max_id from table_a) a
where not exists (select 1 from a_table a where a.b = b.b);
```

Comment: hey I did some testing and sadly the query buffers for a few minutes with no output
I guess its because the 5.000.000 entry's in both and also the newer entry's are likely to be in the back of the new table

Comment: I just did some testing to check if the value just exist in the TableB and it took 30 to 40secs for a single value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into A_Table (a,b,c)
(select B_Table.a, B_Table.b, B_Table.c from B_Table left join A_Table on 
 A_Table.b=B_Table.b where A_Table.id is null)
```